# Comments about question put on hold

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[Original question found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905775/loop-for-printing-css-style-in-multiple-printed-a-hrefs?noredirect=1#comment31398549_20905775)

Comments:

To those who have put the question on hold I do apologise, I am new to the forum and fairly new to programming. I can't see however why this question is not clear?

**I am simply asking how to style links with a color.**

The links are being printed by way of a PHP print statement

**I was asking for possibilities and the available alternatives which may have worked for me to achieve this.**

Considering the fact that I have also marked this question as solved and was given an answer which satisfied my requirement by one of the helpful members, I was obviously understood by that person and a couple of others who made suggestions which were more than likely beyond my skill grade.

I am not concerned that the question has been put on hold because as I mentioned previously I have found an answer and marked it as solved.

I am however concerned that 5 of you, who I do believe didn't even try to ask or comment about my problem are so quick to mark this as not being somewhat clear. It's a bit hard to spell out letter for letter EXACTLY what a question is about in any coding scenario and I'm guessing that if I put too much information then it would be a case of being too "broad"?

I have read the rules but your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Of note, SO is not a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'too much information' if the information is relevant. Keep in mind that having your question put on hold is not the end of the road: improve the question and ask for a reopen.

What I would suggest for you in the future is to always add a sentence to the end of your question that summarizes what you want. Something along the lines of "How can I add a style to my links without having to explicitly specify it for every link?".
This way it's a lot easier for people to spot the core question and they will have something specific to answer to.

I have to say that at first glance I didn't quite understood what it is you wanted, but reading the answer and the comments clarified it. That being said: I'm not a webdev so this was out of my comfortzone in the first place.

Sidenote: I'll edit your question with the beforementioned summarizing sentence and vote to reopen, since I believe the question would definitely be good enough after that.
Whether it was a justified closure I can't answer with certainty, but appearantly 5 members thought it was. I agree though that there should have been more follow up, especially since you specifically asked whether you gave the correct information.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback @Jeroen Vannevel. Points taken onboard

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the close voters thought it was unclear *what you didn't understand* rather than *what your ultimate goal was*. It is extremely helpful to answerers to be specific and detailed about your comprehension of the problem space (however small that space may be). This is why posters are often asked "What have you tried?" -- we want to know what you know so far, so we don't waste time covering ground you've already passed over, or provide too broad an explanation that's going to end up with a 20-comment thread for clarification and debugging below the answer.

Please note that this doesn't have to mean a code snippet. It just means that you should explain what you understand about the nature of the problem you face, and hopefully what solutions you've considered, and why those solutions don't work for you. Different questions require a different degree of formality in laying out that information, but it really should be present in almost any post.

At some point, if it's unclear *enough* where you're at in your search for a solution, closure may be justified because answers will become stabs in the dark or treatises on how to program; those won't really help anybody with a similar problem in the future. The question is closed so that it can be edited, and if it's improved enough, it can be reopened.

I can't say for certain that this is the reason that your question was closed, of course. This is my own feedback based on reading the post (and with no knowledge of the domain).

Comment: As an aside, I have to express appreciation for your constructive attitude in seeking feedback here. We get quite a number of "y u close my Q, nazi modrater?!" posts; this is an absolute relief.

Comment: No problem - I'm here for the collective learning environment that the internet is meant to be and to help where I can if at all possible. Every forum has it's different elements but like I said - I personally am not here to argue, flame, troll or any other term used in the space for buttholes with nothing better to do with their time - cheers @Josh Caswell

Comment: Right on, @tokenloko. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks mate - I'll more than likely need it - "THEY" are everywhere! :D